# What is a good way to run a task whenever a Heroku app restarts?

Tags: ruby, heroku

Use case is to bust the cache.

What is a good way to run given code (or rake task) whenever a **Ruby** Heroku app is restarted (or deployed)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this via the Heroku API far as I know. The Heroku Platform API doesn't support this.

What you can do (if you're fast, however!) is listen for a SIGTERM message in your code (that's what Heroku sends to your application process when it attempts to restart it) -- you can then fire off your script quickly.

Here's more information on SIGTERM on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm

Comment: Another solution is to subscribe to your Heroku logs via a log drain (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) then listen for the dyno restart log event, and fire off some external task then as well.

Comment: Who is doing the listening?

Comment: You can subscribe your own listeners on an EC2 instance, and parse the logs on there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using some sort of CI, you can probably configure it there. Heres how to do it with CircleCI:

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: production
    commands:
      - git push git@heroku.com:foo-bar-123.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:master
      - heroku run rake <your task> --app <your app name>
```

If you're not using a CI you can still whip together a script that first does the git push to Heroku and then executes your cache busting task through `heroku run` (the app's `bin/` folder would be an obvious place to put it).

Note: you can also use `heroku run:detached`, which will send output to your logs instead of stdout.

Comment: Part of this use case is that Heroku app is restarted for other reasons than deploy. Specifically for changing ENV.

Comment: Well, you can always write two scripts, or one script that's modular. Just check if the first argument to the script is "deploy", then deploy and flush cache. If it's "restart" modify any ENV variables you need (pass it in), then restart and flush. Not that hard really.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "release" feature that allows you to run any command before a new release is deployed. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase

Define the command that should be run in your Procfile.

```
release: rake db:migrate
```

From documentation:

> The release command is run immediately after a release is created, but before the release is deployed to the app’s dyno formation. That means it will be run after an event that creates a new release.